# Returning a sum of squares function

Tags: python, sum, return

So I need to write a program that takes three user inputs, a lower and upper bound, and the type of function to do (square, cube, inverse)
So far, I have

```
def main():
    global func
    lower = int(input("Enter the lower bound for summation: "))
    upper = int(input("Enter the upper bound for summation: "))
    func = str(input("Enter a function to be summed (Square, cube, inverse)"))
    summation(lower,upper)
def summation(low,high):
    tot = 0
    if func.lower() == 'square' and low < high:
        for i in range(low, high + 1):
            sqr = i**2
            tot += sqr
    return tot
    if func.lower() == 'cube' and low < high:
        for i in range(low, high + 1):
            cub = i**3
            tot += cub
    return tot
    if func.lower() == 'inverse' and low < high:
        for i in range(low, high + 1):
            inv = (1/i)
            tot += inv
    return tot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, when I execute the program I get no errors, but just a blank output, no numbers or anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to include some `print()`s

Comment: Try changing the last line of `main()` to `print(summation(lower,upper))`.

Comment: @Alden Because it comes after return and not before, like it should.

Comment: @Alden once you reach a `return` you will break out of the function and the print will be ignored

Comment: For a start, your first return tot statement will execute and the rest of the function won't.  That return needs to be indented one level. So summation may well return 0, but then your main function does nothing with it - you can at least print it. Lastly, you are doing a bit of repetition, and for some reason assigning a global variable space to func. This can be simplified and written more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

A working, minimally modified version would look like this:

```
def main():
    global func
    lower = int(input("Enter the lower bound for summation: "))
    upper = int(input("Enter the upper bound for summation: "))
    func = str(input("Enter a function to be summed (Square, cube, inverse)"))
    print(summation(lower,upper))

def summation(low,high):
    tot = 0
    if func.lower() == 'square' and low < high:
        for i in range(low, high + 1):
            sqr = i**2
            tot += sqr
        return tot

    if func.lower() == 'cube' and low < high:
        for i in range(low, high + 1):
            cub = i**3
            tot += cub
        return tot
    if func.lower() == 'inverse' and low < high:
        for i in range(low, high + 1):
            inv = (1/i)
            tot += inv
        return tot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Although you could remove a bit of the duplication in your code:

```
def summation(low, high, func):
    tot = 0
    fn_select = {'square': lambda x: x**2, 'cube': lambda x: x**3, 'inverse': lambda x: 1/x}
    if low < high:
        for i in ranage(low, high+1):
            tot += fn_select[func](i)
        return(tot)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Lower bound needs to be lower than higher bound')
```

And if you want to compress it further, you can use list comprehension as well, just a code snippet here, eg:

```
tot = sum( [ x**2 for x in range (low, high+1) ])
```

or more generically using the function selector

```
tot = sum( [fn_select[func](x) for x in range(low, high+1) ])
```